# C++ :Why the regular expression pattern"[+-/*]" matches string "."?

Tags: c++, regex

What's wrong with the regular expression I used?

```
#include<regex>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    smatch results;
    string temp("[+-/*]");
    string test(".");

    regex r(temp);

    if(regex_search(test,results,r))
        cout<<results.str()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

"." will be print out and if I use '\' to create escape sequence like:

```
string temp("[\\+-/\\*]");
```

The output remains.

Comment: Look into raw strings from C++11 - they're great!

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `-` is interpreted differently inside character class `[]`, covering characters in a range. This is the interpretation of `-` that lets you define `[A-Z]` to cover all upper-case letters, or `[0-9]` to cover all decimal digits.

If you want to use `-`, place it at the beginning or at the end of the block, or escape it with `\`:

```
string temp("[-+/*]");
```

Otherwise, `[+-/]` covers all characters with codes between `'+'` (43) and `'/'` (47), inclusive, i.e. `'+'`, `','`, `'-'`, `'.'`, and `'/'`.